# How to show the labels of aeroways like Openstreetmap in Mapbox Studio

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox Studio to create a Mapbox style.

However, I don't know how to show the labels of aeroways like [Openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/16.0520/108.2044).

You can see the labels are showing on the right side.

[image: The labels are showing on the right side]

Comment: just for the records: also posted in https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/44307/how-to-show-the-labels-of-aeroways-like-openstreetmap-in-mapbox-studio